# WPF get ListBox TextSearch text and pass it to Label

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have simple ListBox with few items, which I can search by TextSearch. How to get text from keyboard (TextSearch.Text) and pass it to Label ?

```
<Window x:Class="Etykiety.Szablony"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Etykiety"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Szablony" Height="350" Width="250" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:SzablonGridViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Background="#FFF6A300">
    <ListBox x:Name="SzablonyBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Szablonyy, IsAsync=True}"
             SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
             MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
             Background="{x:Null}" TextSearch.Text="BLABLAB"
             TextSearch.TextPath="Nazwa" IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewKeyDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nazwa}" FontWeight="Bold"
                               FontSize="15" Height="35"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               TextAlignment="Justify"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Label x:Name="searchLabel" Content="Label"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="72,69,0,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

I just use `TextSearch.Text="BLABLABLA"` and I can pass it to Label, but only at start. How can I get "live" text from searching ? I mean, I would like to have something like preview what I'm typing. Do I have to bind this textsearch somehow ?

Comment: `TextSearch.Text` is not what you think. You can read in docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch(v=vs.110).aspx what it's really used for.

Comment: @Evk Right. Is there any event that handles if I type text in TextSearch ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.